# Show/Hide div using jquery - Not working

Tags: jquery

I am using this function to show/hide a div.

But this is not working.

It's working only for hide and not working for show. And i need to show and hide the fields in slow style.

How can this be done?

what was my mistake here...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#field-reviewers-items").hide();
    $('#edit-field-openforreview-value-1').click(function(){
        $("#field-reviewers-items").show();
    });
    $('#edit-field-openforreview-value-1').click(function(){
        $("#field-reviewers-items").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the click method twice, meaning `$.hide()` will run immediately after `$.show()`. This takes place so quickly that it seems as though `$.show()` isn't even working. Instead, set the click once and instruct it to toggle the visibility:

```
$("#edit-field-openforreview-value-1").click(function(){
  $("#field-reviewers-items").fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

This code assumes you wanted the same element to toggle the visibility of the `#field-reviewers-items` element; I felt this was a safe assumption since your selector was the same for both click events. It's possible that you had a typo though, and the second selector was supposed to be `value-2` instead:

```
var $fieldRevItems = $("#field-reviewers-items");

$("#edit-field-openforreview-value-1").click(function(){
  $fieldRevItems.show('slow');
});

$("#edit-field-openforreview-value-2").click(function(){
  $fieldRevItems.hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#edit-field-openforreview-value-1').click(function() {
    $("#field-reviewers-items").fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

Showing/hiding in "slow" style